# How to Undo Changes to Binding on Button Press, given TextField re-renders view each time

Tags: swiftui

For a specific view, I have added a popup sheet that appears when an edit button is pressed. I would like to add a cancellation button and a save button to this view. How could I revert the changes made to the binding variable when pressing the cancellation button.

Higher Level View

```
@State var editView:Bool = false
...
Button(action:
{
    editView = true
}, label: {
    Image(systemName: "pencil.circle")
}).sheet(isPresented: $editView)
...
```

EditingView

```
struct EditView: View {
    @Binding var editView:Bool
    @State var editingTask:Task
    @Binding var task:Task

    init(editView: Binding<Bool>, task: Binding<Task>) {
        self._editView = editView
        self._editingTask = State(initialValue: task.wrappedValue)
        self._task = task
    }
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack
        {
            HStack
            {
                Button(action: {
                    editView = false
                }, label:
                {
                    Text("Cancel")
                 })
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    editView = false
                    self.task = editingTask
                }, label:
                {
                    Text("Save")
                 })
            }
            TextField("Task Name", text: $editingTask.name)
        }
    }
}
```

**What I Tried:**

I noticed there was a solution on StackExchange that uses a state variable that is a copy of the Binding variable passed in. This did not work as I could not edit the textfield. I don't think this worked because the view is re-initialized each time a textfield value changes, so the temporary state variable is re-initialized to the original value.

Link to solution here: [Is there a way to "unbind" variables/objects in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860624/is-there-a-way-to-unbind-variables-objects-in-swiftui)

Sometimes I will see an additional letter I typed in the TextField flash on the screen in the editView when I spam the keyboard. I imagine this is because the view was not refreshed fast enough.

I also tried adding a cancellation item using a toolbar cancellation time, and that didn't work either. I imagine this is because I am not using a NavigationLink hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I made a state variable that indicated the various fields of the task class. This fields were initialized using .onAppear {}. Then, if the user clicks the save button, then the properties of the task are updated using these state fields.

E.g.

```
@State var editingTaskName:String = ""

TextField("Name", text: $editingTaskName)
    .onAppear()
    {
        let name = String(task.name)
        editingTaskName = name
    }
```

Once name is validated on press of save button, the task is updated.

```
if(editingTaskName.isValid()) {task.name = editingTaskName}
```

Comment: Your initial plan to edit a copy of the bound variable sounds like a better approach. Still, if this solution worked for you, may I suggest expanding on your answer to include the working code?

Comment: Done, though I am curious what the "right" way to do it is

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have been on the right track, but your `Task` object is a class, as opposed to a struct. If this is true, `@State` has generally been intended for value types (i.e. structs) only, so you may get unexpected behavior when using `@State` with reference types (i.e. classes). However, as of iOS 17 you can use the `Observable()` macro. [Apple offers some helpful documentation for switching your `ObservableObject` class over to the new `Observable()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro).

So if you previously had:

```
class Task: ObservableObject {
  @Published var name: String
  // more properties here
}
```

You'd then have:

```
@Observable class Task {
  var name: String
  // more properties here
}
```

This should allow you to define `@State private var editingTask: Task` as you originally intended, and bind UI elements to `Task` properties.