# How to cancel edits to @Binding var when dismissing detail view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, data-binding

I have a to-do list app. Tasks are `@ObservableObject`s displayed in a list. Users can open a detail view to edit task properties (due date, location, schedule, notes, etc.).

I have Save and Cancel buttons at the top of this detail sheet. Saving or discarding changes to persistent storage works fine and dismisses the detail sheet, returning the user to the list. However, when tapping Cancel the edited version still shows in the list. I want a clean way to revert all changes made in that detail sheet without mucking up my code.

Here's a simplified version of what I have going on. Feel free to skim a little (or a lot), I left some extra detail in to demonstrate why other solutions I've found on here feel like the wrong way to go.

```
struct TaskListView: View {
  
  @State private var selectedTask: Binding<TaskItemEditorViewModel>? = nil
  
  @ObservedObject private var taskList: TaskListViewModel
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach($taskList.nextActions, id: \.uuid) { task in
        TaskListRow(task: task)
          .swipeActions {
            Button {
              selectedTask = task
            } label: {
              editSwipeActionLabel
            }
          }
      }
    }
    .sheet(item: $selectedTask, onDismiss: { selectedTask = nil }) { task in
      NavigationView {
        TaskDetailView(dataStack: dataSource, draftTask: task)
      }
    }
  }

}

struct TaskDetailView: View {
  
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  
  @State private var notesModalIsPresented = false
  @Binding private var draftTask: TaskItemEditorViewModel
  
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      Section(header: Text("I need to...")) {
        TextEditor(text: $draftTask.title)
          .font(.headline)
          .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        PriorityStepper(priority: $draftTask.priority)
      }
      Section(header: Text("Task repitition & expiration")) {
        ExpirationDatePicker(selectedDate: $draftTask.dueDate, dateIsSet: $draftTask.dueDateIsSet)
        RecurrencePicker(recurrence: $draftTask.recurrence, recurrenceIsSet: $draftTask.hasRecurrence)
      }
      Section(header: Text("Task notes")) {
        if draftTask.hasNotes {
          editNotesButton
          Text(draftTask.notes)
        } else {
          addNotesButton
        }
      }
      Section() {
        HStack {
          Spacer()
          markCompleteButton
          Spacer()
        }
      }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $notesModalIsPresented, content: {
      NotesEditor(notesText: $draftTask.notes, taskHasNotes: $draftTask.hasNotes, isPresented: $notesModalIsPresented)
    })
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: saveButton)
    .navigationBarItems(leading: cancelButton)

  }
  
  private var saveButton: some View {
    return Button {
      // this saves to persistent storage
      try? draftTask.saveChanges()
      dismiss()
    } label: {
      Text("Done")
    }
  }
  
  private var cancelButton: some View {
    return Button {
      // this basically restores the original properties,
      // before any changes were made on this screen
      draftTask.revertChanges()
      dismiss()
    } label: {
      Text("Cancel")
    }
  }
}
```

As shown above, I tried simply calling my view model's `.revertChanges`. This restores all properties to what was last retrieved from the database -- i.e., the original state before opening up the detail view. However, this is not reflected when the user returns to `TaskListView`. Any changes made there are still hanging around (though not saved to the database).

I also tried copying the @Binding var into a @State var, editing that, then copying changes back (or not) when the sheet is dismissed, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860624/is-there-a-way-to-unbind-variables-objects-in-swiftui).

So I then had in `TaskDetailView`:

```
@Binding var sourceTask: TaskItemEditorViewModel
@State var draftTask: TaskItemEditorViewModel
```

Initialized like this:

```
init(draftTask: Binding<TaskItemEditorViewModel>) {
    self._sourceTask = draftTask
    self._draftTask = State(initialValue: draftTask.wrappedValue)
}
```

Only problem is, the bindings (text fields, steppers, pickers, etc.) no longer worked with the `@State` as opposed to `@Binding`.

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267192/how-to-undo-changes-to-binding-on-button-press-given-textfield-re-renders-view) seems to have worked around that by adding a bunch of extra code `.onAppear`, additional `@State` variables for their object properties (e.g. my `$draftTask.title`, `$draftTask.priority`, etc.).

I haven't even tried that workaround because to me it defeats the whole purpose of SwiftUI. I already have a working version of my app built entirely in UIKit. That tangle of code is a big reason why I'm converting views like this one to SwiftUI and taking advantage of bindings.

As stated in the first SO thread I linked here, this behavior is evident in the iOS Contacts app, among many others. You can open up an edit mode, then choose to either save your changes or cancel. After a crap ton of Googling and trial and error, I feel like I must be missing something so obvious but I can't find it for the life of me.

Edit for clarification: Both view model types are classes, not structs.

Comment: It’s confusing what you mean by view model, is it a view model or the actual model object? And are they class or struct types?

Comment: The cleanest way is to not affect the source of truth until changes are final. Make a copy of the object to edit and then save to the source of truth.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's a view model, class type.

Comment: @loremipsum you mean as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860624/is-there-a-way-to-unbind-variables-objects-in-swiftui)? I would be happy to do that except I haven't found a way to make it work. Doing as described in that link sounded like the best option, except bindings to UI elements (e.g. priority stepper) didn't function correctly.

Comment: So the main view model has an array of view models, for me this is incorrect. You should have one view model per view so when yo show the TaskDetailView view a new view model instance is created for that view (and the view model loads the data from storage).

Comment: Yes, that should work. There are other ways but that is a possibility.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson not sure I follow -- which do you mean by "main view model?"

Comment: TaskListViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `Binding<TaskItemEditorViewModel>` and the `State(initialValue: draftTask.wrappedValue)` that is non-standard SwiftUI.

The way Apple recommend to solve this is make a `@State` struct to hold the the detail data. See `EditorConfig` in [Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020 at 4:18](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020-10040/?time=256)

FYI you shouldn't use classes for view data (i.e. view models) since that is what the `View` struct is designed for. Only use objects when you need reference semantics, i.e. asynchronous loading.

Comment: >> FYI you shouldn't use classes for view data (i.e. view models) since that is what the View struct is designed for.

This is the key I think. Thank you for linking that video. I had lost the plot a bit and was trying to use the `@State` wrapper on a class. Converted it to a struct and got it working.

Curious though, are you saying custom inits for views are bad practice? Or just the way I implemented in this example?

Comment: Because the property wrapper instance var design is designed to prevent you from supplying a param which would violate the single source of truth design for state. You shouldn't be using draft task as the initial value every state needs to be init with a constant initial value

Comment: Then I assume you also disagree with the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860624/is-there-a-way-to-unbind-variables-objects-in-swiftui) about implementing a Cancel feature when editing a `@Binding` var. What would you do instead, to achieve that same result?